# Is it possible to show parameter values in the log when using auto_explain?

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to find the answer for this, but can't seem to find it and it's really starting to get to me.

I've started using "auto_explain" to see the query plans of what goes on inside of Postgres functions and it's a really great tool.  The problem I'm having, though, is that I can't see the actual values of parameters in the log and I'd like to, if it's possible.  Here's an example from a log file:

```
Query Text: SELECT AppSettingValue                          FROM sAppSetting

    WHERE LOWER(ConfigFileName) = LOWER(p_configFileName)

        AND LOWER(AppSettingKey) = LOWER(p_appSettingKey)
Index Scan using idx_sappsetting_lower_appsettingkey_configfilename on sappsetting  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((lower((appsettingkey)::text) = lower($2)) AND (lower((configfilename)::text) = lower($1)))
  Buffers: shared hit=3
```

In the query plan above, you can see "$2" and "$1", but I can't figure out how to reveal the actual values being used there.

I'm running Postgres 10.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the parameters with `auto_explain`.

But you can see that PostgreSQL uses the “generic plan” that does not take the values of the parameters into account.